# Automator Eject Action - OSStatus error -36

Tags: applescript, catalina, automator

Hopefully quick question:

I've made an automator quick action to eject all BUT the disks that are always hanging around my computer. It uses an AppleScript to get the list of disks, strip it of the local HD, "VM", "Home", and "Google Drive", since I don't need to eject those. I pass those to a shell script that just outputs each item after prepending "/Volumes/" to the name. This goes to an "Eject Disk" action, which is followed by a notification. The disks eject properly, but I get the OSStatus error -36, which causes it to stop after the eject action rather than display the notification and pop up an error. I can't find that error code via a google search - any ideas?

Error dialog:

[image: Automator Error Dialog]

Automator Script:

[image: Automator Script]

Answer (score 1):

If you are going use **AppleScript** to get a *list of disks* you want *ejected*, then simply use, e.g.:

```
tell application "Finder" to eject cleanListOfDisks
```

Then there is no need to pass `cleanListOfDisks` to a **Run Shell Script** *action* to then pass it to a **Eject Disk** *action*.

---

Here is how I'd *code* the **Run AppleScript** *action*  and not use any other *actions*:

```
set listOfDisks to list disks
set doNotEjectDiskList to {"Macintosh HD", "VM", "home", "net", "Google Drive"}
set listOfDisksToEject to {}

repeat with thisDisk in listOfDisks
    if thisDisk is not in doNotEjectDiskList then
        copy contents of thisDisk to end of listOfDisksToEject
    end if
end repeat

tell application "Finder" to eject listOfDisksToEject
```

Comment: That is much simpler - works like a charm!

Comment: @TemperedFool, Please have a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)